# rewrite same url subfolder to different subdirectory with different domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have two seperate domains being hosted on the same server.   The respective subfolders contain seperate instances of a blog.

right now we have:
http://domain.com/blog/
and we would also like
http://anotherdomain.com/blog/

Domain.com's blog folder will need to be served up via a folder in:
/public/blogsoft/domaincom

AnotherDomain.com's blog folder will need to be served up via a folder in:
/public/blogsoft/anotherdomaincom

The /blogsoft/ folder cannot be accessed directly and must be dropped if attempted directly.

The question is can we use just a single htaccess file to accomplish this?

Comment: Try adding the following to `.htaccess` in the parent directory above the directory of interest: `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /foo/bar/` or `RedirectMatch ^/foo/$ /bar/baz/`. Also see [How to get apache2 to redirect to a subdirectory](http://serverfault.com/q/9992/145545).

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTACCES I created to solve the problem.  It should help with anyone that already has an existing site/blog combination and needs to install another site/blog along with it.

```
##### BLOG REDIRECTS **************
#prevent access to blogsoft itself.  TURN THIS OFF IF YOU ARE INSTALLING A NEW BLOG
RewriteRule ^blogsoft/?$ $1/blog$2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blog(.*)$ /blogsoft/domaincom/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.anotherdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?blog(.*)$ /blogsoft/anotherdomain\/$1 [L]

##### EOF BLOG REDIRECTS **************
```